# How to read Excel to Datatable using NPOI C#

Tags: c#, excel, npoi

I'm Trying to read Excel to **DataTable** using **NPOI**.Every thing working fine but only issue is If we have any Column cell is empty in that row it is not reading .In Excel i have 4 row's with (each row have some empty values for cells).

Excel File Image : [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FKCCZ.png)

After Reading That Excel To data table :[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kXQxz.png)

[I want like this in data table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nXcaq.png)

```
        private DataTable GetDataTableFromExcel(String Path)
        {
        XSSFWorkbook wb;
        XSSFSheet sh;
        String Sheet_name;
        using (var fs = new FileStream(Path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
        {
        wb = new XSSFWorkbook(fs);
        Sheet_name = wb.GetSheetAt(0).SheetName;  //get first sheet name
        }
        DataTable DT = new DataTable();
        DT.Rows.Clear();
        DT.Columns.Clear();
        // get sheet
        sh = (XSSFSheet)wb.GetSheet(Sheet_name);
        int i = 0;
        while (sh.GetRow(i) != null)
        {
         // add neccessary columns
         if (DT.Columns.Count < sh.GetRow(i).Cells.Count)
        {
        for (int j = 0; j < sh.GetRow(i).Cells.Count; j++)
        {
            DT.Columns.Add("", typeof(string));
        }
        }
        // add row
        DT.Rows.Add();

        // write row value
        for (int j = 0; j < sh.GetRow(i).Cells.Count; j++)
        {
            var cell = sh.GetRow(i).GetCell(j);
            DT.Rows[i][j] = sh.GetRow(i).GetCell(j);

        }
        i++;
        }
        return DT;
        }
```

Plese hlp me.

Comment: Does it throw exceptions? Does it just skip the line?

Comment: it's skiping cells ..not reading cell values for example please the attached images

Comment: For example In excel i have total 4 rows .. In first row each and every cells have values.In 2nd row  have only value for 2nd cells , 3rd and 4th also same .. but finally it skipping and returning 4 rows .

Comment: Please help i'm trying but I'm not getting what happening here.

Comment: Can you please help me ..it's too urgent guys please

Comment: No one replayed me ho sad .. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you may have to try something along this line. its workable code to read the excel using NPOI.

```
// read the current row data
XSSFRow headerRow = (XSSFRow)sheet.GetRow(0);
// LastCellNum is the number of cells of current rows
int cellCount = headerRow.LastCellNum;
 // LastRowNum is the number of rows of current table
int rowCount = sheet.LastRowNum + 1; 
 bool isBlanKRow = false;
//Start reading data after first row(header row) of excel sheet.

for (int i = (sheet.FirstRowNum + 1); i < rowCount; i++)
{
    XSSFRow row = (XSSFRow)sheet.GetRow(i);
    DataRow dataRow = dt.NewRow();
    isBlanKRow = true;
    try
    {
        for (int j = row.FirstCellNum; j < cellCount; j++)
        {
            if (null != row.GetCell(j) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(row.GetCell(j).ToString()) && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(row.GetCell(j).ToString()))
            {
                dataRow[j] = row.GetCell(j).ToString();
                isBlanKRow = false;
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception Ex)
     { 

     }
     if (!isBlanKRow)
     {
         dt.Rows.Add(dataRow);
     }

}
```